# Grouping items programmatically in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

*I have a navigation drawer in my application. I have added the menu items programmatically as per the following script.. I want to group certain items as an expandable list view, but am not sure how to go about it.

```
 private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
Toolbar toolbar;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences pref;
ProgressDialog pd;
Token token = new Token();
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    setupToolbar();
    TextView mail, name;
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

    DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[7];
    drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_home, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[0]);
    drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_local_grocery_store, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[1]);
    drawerItem[2] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_collections, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[2]);
    drawerItem[3] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_payment, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[3]);
    drawerItem[4] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_wc, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[4]);
    drawerItem[5] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_wc, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[5]);
    drawerItem[6] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_settings_power, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array)[6]);




    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);



    mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header_email);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.agentname);

    pref = getSharedPreferences(Config.MAIN, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = pref.getString(Config.USER_EMAIL, "");
    String aname = pref.getString(Config.AGENTName, "");
    Log.e("email", email);
    Log.e("aname", aname);

    mail.setText(email);
    name.setText(aname);

    setupDrawerToggle();
    selectItem(0);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.laurel.radius/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.laurel.radius/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    client.disconnect();
}

int x = 0;

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position - 1);
    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            x = position;
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            x = position;
            fragment = new MycollectionReportFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            x = position;
            fragment = new PendingCollectionFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            x = position;
            fragment = new ReceivecashpaymentFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            x = position;
            fragment = new RegistrationFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            x = position;
            fragment = new CollectionHistory();
            break;
        case 6:
            logout();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position + 1, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

void logout() {
   /* String tokenid=pref.getString(Config.TOKEN_VALUE,"");*/
    // editor.putString(Config.USER, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    String log = getResources().getString(R.string.Logoutapp);
    alertDialog.setTitle(log);
    String exit = getResources().getString(R.string.closethisapplication);
    alertDialog.setMessage(exit);
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //dialog.cancel();
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(x + 1, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(x);
                setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[x]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }

        }
    });
```

*i take values from string.xml
    `<string-array name="navigation_drawer_items_array">
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>My Collections</item>
        <item>Pending Collections</item>
        <item>Recive Cash</item>
        <item>New Registration </item>
        <item>Collection History</item>
        <item>Log Out</item>
    </string-array>`*

Answer (score 0):

I would make `DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[7];` a list. Then just use `drawerItem.add("your new drawer item")` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` just like you would for any other list view. Alternatively you can keep things the way they are and add a method to your adapter to pass in a new array and update that way.